# Why didn't Naruto learn the basics of chakra control?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, shinobi battles last a very long time consuming lots of chakra.  Even though Naruto has a lot of chakra, he ignored the basics and started learning high level techniques with Jiraiya.  Even though this wasn't a bad thing, he just kept learning higher levels of techniques without using the basics, causing him to waste more chakra for high level jutsus.

Why hasn't Naruto learned how the use the bare minimum the start his jutsus?

Know that if he did that, he wouldn't have had to rely on the Kyuubi's power and would probably be able the do rasen shuriken one more time, or at least have some chakra left over for retreating or finishing off the opponent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that Naruto is a slow learner and the possibility of Kyuubi's interference, Jiraiya realised it would take him a long time to learn the chakra control, and decided that the benefit gained from it is not worth the time spent. Since Naruto has abundant chakra reserves, Jiraiya decided that learning how to tap it is of higher priority than chakra control.

Moreover, many of the times when Naruto learned a new technique (Frog Summoning, Rasengan, Rasenshuriken, Sage Mode, Kyuubi chakra mode), he had to do it within some time limit, so he could not take his own sweet time learning chakra control, and hence, sticked to his original learning method. It is possible that Jiraiya did teach Naruto some chakra control during the time they travelled together, but there is not enough evidence of this happening.

Note that when Naruto began training with Ebisu during the one month training break before the Chunin exam finals, Ebisu did tell him to learn to use his chakra more efficiently. However, after Jiraiya took over his training, he asked Naruto to focus on power rather than control, since he felt that style suited Naruto better.

**Chapter 90**
[image: Ebisu]

**Chapter 92**
[image: Jiraiya]

Comment: However, he can just 'cheat' by using many shadow clones.  So why doesn't he just do that.

Comment: @Blue: Because it's risky to do without Yamato (or Hashirama) around. ***MANGA SPOILER!!!*** Perhaps now, after he's friends with Kurama.

Comment: @Blue I don't get it. After he learnt about the multiple shadow clone method to speed up training, he tried using that everytime, unless someone told him he could not use it. With Sage Mode, he was asked to not make more than 4 clones, and later with the Kyuubi mode, he was asked not to make any clones at all. So it is not like he doesn't do that, he is not "allowed" to do it for other reasons.

Comment: Yes but this is for basics meaning he won't waste so much chakara for jutsus like rasen-shuriken, and since Naruto has so much chakara, he just need to mass clones not to the point in where he will turn kyubii but rather just to get the experience.  All Naruto is doing is learning how to manipulate Chakara from himself, rather than using the Chakra around him.  The reason Sage Mode was limited was because of the risk(if one clone turns into a frog he turns into a frog) also the difficulty of hitting the clones.  The point is, that he can do more jutsus when he controls his chakara.

Comment: I get it now, so you are saying he could get over the "it takes too much time to learn" by using mass shadow clones. There may be three reasons why he doesn't. 1. Nobody has pointed that out to him, and even though he has become smarter, he is still too stupid to figure that out himself. 2. Author did not see much value in pursuing that thread now. Naruto has become too badass now, and it would be lame to pursue an arc like that. 3. Author did not think of it this way. He is a human after all with weekly deadlines, he cannot think of all possible scenarios. :)

Answer (score 1):

By the time he is likely a jounin by *The Last: Naruto the Movie* 2 years after the Kaguya fight, he can form a rasen shuriken with a single hand. His control was so great and progressed so much during the war, he was able to share chakra with everyone. Basically, the Kyuubi was in the way and when he was no longer in the way, his abilities shot up and his control became so much greater because he had to train in 'higher gravity'.

Conclusion, he was constantly improving his control, but the Kyuubi was interfering throughout most of his life so he had to gain more control than the average person to make up for it. When he no longer had interference, it was no longer a problem.

Comment: kinda makes sense